# awk to add row # skipping header

Tags: awk

I am trying to add a line number before each row in skipping the header using `awk`.  However the below seems to be removing the header and starting the line number at `2`.  Am I close?  Thank you :).

**input**

```
Chr Start   End Gene
chrX 110961329 110961512 ALG13
chrX 110987885 110988142 ALG13
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR>1{print NR, $0}' input
```

**current output**

```
2 chrX 110961329 110961512 ALG13
3 chrX 110987885 110988142 ALG13
```

**desired output**

```
1 chrX 110961329 110961512 ALG13
2 chrX 110987885 110988142 ALG13
```

Comment: please also indicate what is the desired output. It is important

Comment: Sorry I added it but it looks like everything is working.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print an output even when the number line is 1

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $0} NR>1{print NR-1, $0}' input

Chr Start   End Gene
1 chrX 110961329 110961512 ALG13
2 chrX 110987885 110988142 ALG13
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanations :)

Answer (score 4):

You are just printing if you are in line number > 1.

Instead, prepend NR when it is bigger than one; then, say `1` so that all the lines will be printed:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%d%s", NR, OFS}1' file
Chr Start   End Gene
2 chrX 110961329 110961512 ALG13
3 chrX 110987885 110988142 ALG13
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanations :)

Comment: OK so if you wanted to start from 1 in the 2nd row, replace `NR` with `NR-1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print (NR>1 ? NR-1 OFS : "") $0}' file
```